# Remote Processor / Memory usage of Specific Process

Tags: powershell, memory, cpu

I'm doing a project to grab the CPU usage %, as well as RAM usage (in KB) for specific processes, about 6.

I came across a [great guide](https://www.pdq.com/blog/powershell-get-cpu-usage-for-a-process-using-get-counter/) for getting cpu%, which uses this code:

```
# Option A: This is if you just have the name of the process; partial name OK
$ProcessName = "winlogon"

# Option B: This is for if you just have the PID; it will get the name for you
#$ProcessPID = "6860"

#$ProcessName = (Get-Process -Id $ProcessPID).Name

$CpuCores = (Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem).NumberOfLogicalProcessors
$Samples = (Get-Counter "\Process($Processname*)\% Processor Time").CounterSamples
$Samples | Select InstanceName,
    @{Name="CPU %";Expression={[Decimal]::Round(($_.CookedValue / $CpuCores), 2)}}
```

However, I cannot find a way to get it to hit remote machines as well. I can use this to list local processes, and I've tried adding the `-ComputerName` switch with a PC Name to the `Get-WmiObject` to grab the remote processor count. This causes the script to fail at `Select`. I've also tried hard-coding the `$CpuCores` value with 2 and using `Get-Counter` against a remote machine, but I'm not sure how to format it given the specific example.

I have no issue writing this from scratch, but I'm having a rough time figuring out how to get either the CPU or RAM usage of specific processes. The end goal is to display the results in a TextBox control that would be readable by Name, CPU % utilization, and memory utilization.

I have the GUI that takes a PC name, and a textbox for the results, I'm having trouble developing the logic to even get the data I need. Any thoughts? I've spent about 2 days combing the Internet and found many methods for both CPU and memory usage, but nothing that I can stick together, or use remotely. I'm not new to PowerShell, but this has been perplexing. Any help in developing the logic would be appreciated.

Comment: "*This causes the script to fail at "Select".*" - Fail how, fail with what error? "*Any thoughts?* - fix the cause of the failure, then it might work.

Comment: I managed to bypass the issue with it failing at Select by recoding the Get Counter section.

This worked, I can now grab cpu util of a single process. However, now I'm trying to wrap it in a foreach Loop. I've setup the array as follows

$Processes = ("Name1", "Name2", "Name3")
I then wrap the logic in a foreach loop using foreach ($element in $Processes)
However, I'm not sure how to format:

(Get-Counter -Computer pcName “\Process($Processes*)\% Processor Time”).CounterSamples

for the array. $Processes[$element]* does not work. I've tried a few different variations for this.